# Laravel : Records from two tables

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models `Award` and `GotAward`, `GotAward` model have foreign key of `Award` model.

What i want to fetch all records from `Award` model and then check each `Award` model id in `GotAward` model, I have to show the user that "you have have these awards".

I have the following code :

```
$awards = App\Award::all();

foreach ($awards as $checkAward) {
    $unlockedAwards = App\unlockedAward::where('award_id','=',$awards->id);
}
```

Is it a good practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GotAward extends Model
{

    public function award(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Award');
        //You can also specify the relationship in case of different fields in the DB table. By convention Laravel will check award_id in gotawards table
/* return $this->hasOne('App\Award', 'award_id', 'gotaward_id');*/

    }


}
```

After you query GotAward Model.

```
$result = $GotAward::where('condtion', 'value')->first();
```

`$result->award->award_column_to_shwo_to_user` Will contain data from awards table.

Take a look at Eloquent relationship,  [here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: I also want all the records in `awards` table i mean `Award` model.
I have to show all awards to the user and before the award title there will be tick or cross sign if he have/have not the award.
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

No
please look into [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

after specifying the hasMany in your Award Model you could do somthing like
`$award->AllAwards()`

Answer (score 0):

use [Laravel Eleoquent Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)